# C# Windows application - run at client but database at webserver

Tags: c#, json, web-services, webserver, windows

I have a windows database application in c#. Database is sql server.
It has 4 layers
   1. UI Layer
   2. BLL
   3. DAL
   4. Data Models

My client has 3 branches in different locations.
So, I want to host the database at a web server and install windows application at clients multiple branches. I know, windows applications are run at client while web application is run at server.
So, to achieve the above, i know that some rework is required in my windows application design, like, - using json for fetching and sending data to/from server etc.
No i am fetching all required data in each form's load event. suppose 5 combobox are to be filled with data, 5 different datatables are being created and used as datasource of each combobox, while if the data is from web server, this approach may affect the performance of the application (i guess). so need to fetch all necessary data for a form at one time (i guess).

These are my doubts and blank ares. 
Any experts detailed advise is highly appreciated in this regard so that i can dig into it and move on.

After doing this, my plan is to develop a parallel web UI and some android modules for this application. I heard RESTful web api can be helpful for this.

pls give your expert opinion.

Thanks in advance
Jim

Comment: You've got it all right (basically) but aren't really asking a question yet. Please ask a specific question; this isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: thanks for quick response. My question is to achieve the above subject matter, what things to be changed in the windows application development?.

Comment: That unfortunately still seems too broad (lots of things could change based on your code). The *general* answer is instead of directly accessing your database, you access the web server. Could you be *any* more specific?

Comment: i will try, as i mentioned above, my bll and dal are in the same solution which completely runs at client. But, since the database is at webserver, is that the right approach to detach my bll and dal from the solution and create it as separate projects and host in the webserver? so that i can access it from any UI layer. is that the correct way? is it possible?. if this is correct, as which type those bll and dal to be made? such as RESTful api or dll or what format? hope this is more clear so that you can advise me more specifically.

Comment: How about using web service by fetching data from your client? just sharing some option.